# Animations / OpenGL (ES 2) in game menu

Tags: android

(I am specifically asking for Android)

If you look at Angry Birds (and in fact many other games), you can already see a lot of animations & effects going in the main menu and in other places even before starting to play. I assume they are done with OpenGL, more precisely a `FrameLayout` is used and inside it a `GLSurfaceView` is somewhere at the bottom of the hierarchy; above the `GLSurfaceView` you have regular Android buttons and texts.

Is this how it's done*? Also would you reuse the same `GLSurfaceView` when running the actual game or should another one be created?

*I am aware an alternative approach would be to make absolutely everything in OpenGL. Of these two I prefer the `FrameLayout` one, but I don't know whether other developers agree.

Comment: Why would you prefer `FrameLayout`? When making games, it is very common to create a GL environment, and do all the drawing in there.

Answer (score 1):

The UI animations for games like Angry Birds is almost always done manually, i.e. not using platform specific elements. The reason of course being that the game will be released on multiple platforms. Using platform specific code will require rewriting it for each target platform, and even then there may be slight differences in how the end result looks and behaves.